# Execute Parallel.ForEach based in a List that needs to receive more items in execution time

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel.foreach

I have a challenge here, and it's giving me a headache to find a solution.

I have a `List` of something, and I execute the `Parallel.ForEach` based on it:

```
List<Customer> customers = GetNotProcessedCostumer(); 

Parallel.ForEach(customers, new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2},
cust=> 
{
     ExecuteSomething(cust);
});
```

The problem here is that I need to call `GetNotProcessedCostumer` again to check if new not processed items are available on database, while this parallel is still running.
Call the method again is OK, but, how can I insert new items in the `List` that the parallel is already using ?

In others words, the `List<Customer>` is alive, and I need to insert items all the time on it, and try to use the available threads in the existing `Parallel`. Take a look:

```
List<Customer> customers = GetNotProcessCustomer // get not processed customers from database

Parallel.ForEach(customers) // ...... Start the parallel ... 

customer.Add(GetNotProcessCustomer()) // Read database again..
```

"Hey Parallel, do you have any thread available ?" If yes, use it.

I can accept others approaches and ideas, like `Threads`, `ThreadPool`.........

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Sound like a producer/consumer thing where you want a queue. You fill the queue with data from GetNotProcessedCostumer periodically and another thread that checks the queue for new items and how many threads are allready running and starts an async version of ExecuteSomething.

Comment: I agree.  Look up Producer/Consumer queues.

Comment: Besides i like the Costumer typo

Comment: Yes, you are right. Queue is the best approach to solve this. Thanks guys, I found a way using queue!

Comment: Gabriel you might consider posting your solution [as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so that other people can benefit from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably better ways to do this job than the `Parallel` class, with an [`ActionBlock<Customer>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) from the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library being the most promising candidate. But if you want to do your job using the knowledge you already have, you could feed the parallel loop with a deferred `IEnumerable<Customer>` sequence instead of a materialized `List<Customer>`. This sequence will be querying the database and yielding the not-processed customers in a never ending loop. It might be a good idea to add a [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay) in the mix, to ensure that the database will not be queried more frequently than every X seconds.

```
IEnumerable<Customer> GetNotProcessedCustomersNonStop(
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var delayTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), cancellationToken);
        foreach (var customer in GetNotProcessedCustomers())
            yield return customer;
        delayTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

Adding a [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken) in the mix is probably also a good idea, because eventually you want to stop the loop, don't you?

If you are not familiar with deferred enumerable sequences and the `yield` statement, you can take a look at this document: [Iterators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators)

One final important detail is to tell the `Parallel` class that you don't want it to do fancy things, like enumerating greedily the enumerable and caching its items. You want it to grab the next customer only when it's ready to process it. You can do it by throwing a [`Partitioner.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create) in the mix. Putting everything together:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

var source = Partitioner.Create(GetNotProcessedCustomersNonStop(cts.Token),
    EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);

var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2,
    CancellationToken = cts.Token,
};

Parallel.ForEach(source, parallelOptions, customer =>
{
    ProcessCustomer(customer);
});

//cts.Cancel(); // eventually...
```